# Drag and drop Multiple html elements at once

Tags: javascript, html

### Is there a HTML5 default way for dragging and dropping -multiple- elements into another html element on the same page?

It seems the HTML5 attribute `draggable`, which applies to one element says: "You can drag me, but you'd need multiple input devices to select another draggable element at the same time."

As a workaround one can add identifiers to selected elements using js and get all selected elements on a certain event and do what we want. But is this really the "correct" way?

When you inspect the `drop` event there is an interface for multiple files, when handling file drag and drop. And there is also the `items` property- at least in Chrome.

There are differences across browsers.

### In Chrome

The `drop` event contains the `items` property

```
dataTransfer: DataTransfer
    items: DataTransferItemList
        length: 0
```

`Items` seems to be 0, no matter if you dragged an item or not.

### In Firefox

The `drop` event contains the `mozItemCount` property

```
dataTransfer: DataTransfer
    mozItemCount: 1
```

`mozItemCount` seems to be at least 1.

---

### Here is a little demo

Where you can observe your developer tools console:

**This source was taken from here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/**

```js
$(function(){
  // Copied from: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/
  var cols_ = document.querySelectorAll('.column');
  var dragSrcEl_ = null;

  handleDragStart = function(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);

    dragSrcEl_ = this;

    this.style.opacity = '0.4';

    // this/e.target is the source node.
    $(this).addClass('moving');
  };

  handleDragOver = function(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Allows us to drop.
    }

    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';

    return false;
  };

  handleDragEnter = function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('over');
  };

  handleDragLeave = function(e) {
    // this/e.target is previous target element.

    $(this).removeClass('over');
  };

  handleDrop = function(e) {
    // this/e.target is current target element.
    console.log(e.dataTransfer);

    if (e.stopPropagation) {
      e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
    }

    // Don't do anything if we're dropping on the same column we're dragging.
    if (dragSrcEl_ != this) {
      dragSrcEl_.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
      this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    }

    return false;
  };

  handleDragEnd = function(e) {
    // this/e.target is the source node.
    this.style.opacity = '1';

    [].forEach.call(cols_, function (col) {
      $(col).removeClass('over');
      $(col).removeClass('moving');
    });
  };

  [].forEach.call(cols_, function (col) {
    col.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');  // Enable columns to be draggable.
    col.addEventListener('dragstart', this.handleDragStart, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragenter', this.handleDragEnter, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragover', this.handleDragOver, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragleave', this.handleDragLeave, false);
    col.addEventListener('drop', this.handleDrop, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragend', this.handleDragEnd, false);
  });
});
```

```css
.column {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #666666;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: move;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.column header {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: #000 0 1px;
  box-shadow: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(left center, rgb(0,0,0), rgb(79,79,79), rgb(21,21,21));
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.column {
 transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
}
.column.over {
  border: 2px dashed #000;
}
.column.moving {
  opacity: 0.25;
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
.column .count {
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: #fff 0 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="cols">
  <div class="column">
    <header>C</header>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <header>B</header>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <header>A</header>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

So it looks like the vendors are preparing for multiple item drag and drop, but there seems no be no default. Please correct me if i'am wrong.

I read these articles to better understand dnd

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_and_drop
- http://html5doctor.com/native-drag-and-drop/

Further readings:

- [Definition of `DataTransferItemList`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-datatransferitemlist-interface)
- [MDN's take on the DataTransfer interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer)
- [MDN's non standard approach of multiple drag and drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Dragging_and_Dropping_Multiple_Items#Multiple_Drop_Example)

Comment: To be able to drag multiple elements you would have to select them first. That's something you have to take care of yourself anyway. So it's only natural to add those elements to the list on `dragstart` yourself too.

Comment: @zeroflagL you are correct. But it there a standard list, items could be appended to? I feel the only way now is to use marker classes (or what so ever) and select these items on the fly.

Comment: The standard supports text and files. See `setData` in your example. I personally store the data outside (e.g. in a variable). That gives me every freedom and in the end it doesn't really matter where the data comes from.    You could use `setData` to send a serialized object or array with ids (JSON.stringify / JSON.parse).

Comment: Would this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/vEzXbj) solves the problem? Based on this article: [drag&drop](http://www.sitepoint.com/accessible-drag-drop/)

Comment: @Rotan075 while this is nice and interesting it's still a polyfill. It uses an own implementation of currently selected and dragged elements (see line 42 in the js code). I'd like to know if it's possible to use the native html5 interfaces only. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Nico O yep true!;) difficult question haha. I hope I helped you anyway!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, the `items` length as well as `files` length is working in Chrome. You always get 0 length because the info in the drag data store is protected, except on drop event. So when you log the object and look at it afterwards, you don't have access to the info. But if you log it like this:

```
console.log(e.dataTransfer.items.length);
```

Then you'll have access to the actual length. See here regarding `protected mode`:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-drag-data-store

That is not to say that it'll give you the count of dragged elements, and there are a few reasons as to why:

First thing is that the native `drag and drop API` is also used for
   dragging from the browser to other applications and vice versa. So
   lots of the features in there deal with these cases.

Other thing is that drag and drop API gives you access to things that
   are defaults behaviors of the browser in regard to dragging things. For example, dragging a link in your browser will open the link. When
   you use the API, you're accessing these behaviors.

Many behaviors of this API are a consequence of this and in that sense are not really intended to drag DOM elements around. To this purpose, other libraries are probably more appropriate or simply managing the content itself through the different events it offers.

Since you can drag and drop elements from other applications, a lot of the info has to do with this. For example in `dataTransferItem`, you have access to a `fileList` object. This is only working when dragging files from your OS into the browser. So you have a count of files, and the different files dragged. But this has nothing to do with dragging of `DOM elements`.

You can also drag from the browser. Very useful for example if you want to drag HTML content to Word. But then the info to transfer is more complex than simply the DOM elements. In that case you're dragging `items`, but these `items` are not the DOM elements per say. They are the different types of things that can be transfered.

The types of things that can be transfered varies a lot in implementation, but basically you can have plain text, html content and links. So the length of the items will be the length of types available. For example, in the jsfiddle below, on Chrome, you can drag images, links and plain text(for this one you need to select only the text). Result of :

```
 console.log(e.dataTransfer.items.length, 
e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'), 
e.dataTransfer.getData('text/uri-list'), 
e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html'));
```

when draggin each element on the grey target is this:

Plain text from the input :

```
length: 1 
 plain text: text 
 link:  
 html content:
```

From image:

```
length: 2 
    plain text:  
     link: http://www.exiv2.org/include/img_1771.jpg 
     html content: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"><img id="image1" src="http://www.exiv2.org/include/img_1771.jpg">
```

From link:

```
length: 3 
 plain text: http://google.com/ 
 link: http://google.com/ 
 html content: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"><a href="http://google.com/">link 1</a>
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ztj6t2ff/9/

You'll see that the `html` is not exactly what you have on your page. This is to allow transfer to other applications and keep the best formatting possible.

So in general, this `API` allows you to interfere with default behaviors of dragging almost anything you can drag in your OS in and from the browser. In that sense it's pretty complex, but most of the features have nothing to do with dragging DOM elements inside a same page.

And in fact almost all DOM manipulations through drag and drop are made without using this API. `jquery-ui draggable` for example doesn't rely at all on this API.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive Answer. This is what I was looking for while researching. I posted this question to work on a certain use case and later decided to make it more general. I solved my initial problem using a custom javascript widget. I had problems using `draggable="true"` because: 1) It seems to be not possible to disable the "helper" drag image in IE. 2) Firefox does not contain mouse position in the `dragover` event. And many more. The draggable feature could be awesome, but it is too restricted. To implement a multi drag-out-of-browser feature for example.